# r data.table::dcast cross product fails on large data set

Tags: r, data.table, reshape, dcast, cross-product

i have a `dcast()` application whose cross-product exceeds `.Machine$integer.max`.  is there a recommended alternative to dealing with this situation?  i could break up `w` into smaller pieces, but was hoping for a clean solution.

this might be a duplicate of [R error when applying dcast to a large data.table object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47823520/r-error-when-applying-dcast-to-a-large-data-table-object) but that question also doesn't have an answer.

thanks!

```
library(data.table)

# three million x one thousand
w <- data.table( x = 1:3000000 , y = 1:1000 )

z <- data.table::dcast( w , x ~ y , value.var = 'x' )
# Error in CJ(1:3000000, 1:1000) : 
  # Cross product of elements provided to CJ() would result in 3e+09 rows which exceeds .Machine$integer.max == 2147483647
```

Comment: are you in 32bit or 64bit r?

Comment: R version 3.5.2 (2018-12-20)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 16299)

Answer (score 3):

i guess this solution works if one of your variables is numeric and you also have a sense of the distribution (so can cut it into roughly equal pieces)

```
library(data.table)

# three million x one thousand
w <- data.table( x = 1:3000000 , y = 1:1000 )

z <- data.table::dcast( w , x ~ y , value.var = 'x' )

w[ , cast_cat := findInterval( y , seq( 100 , 900 , 100 ) ) ]
w_list <- split( w , by = 'cast_cat' )
w_list <- lapply( w_list , function( x ) x[ , cast_cat := NULL ] )
w_list <- lapply( w_list , function( z ) data.table::dcast( z , x ~ y , value.var = 'x' ) )
result <- Reduce( function( ... ) merge( ... , by = 'x' , all = TRUE ) , w_list )
```

Comment: Even if the variables aren't numeric or follow an unknown distribution, you could simply add a random number column keyed on the lhs of the `equation` used in `dcast`.

Comment: Can someone explain the `function( ... ) merge( ... , by = 'x', all=TRUE), w_list)` ?

Comment: with the `Reduce` it merges together an unlimited number of data.frame objects rather than only merging two as you would in a normal merge